# Fragment is blank on second load

Tags: android, kotlin, android-viewpager, fragment

App's navigation happens through a `BottomNavigationView`.
On the 1st position, I have a fragment which has button to navigate to another fragment.The first time it loads and shows everything. The, I click on 1st position on BotttomNavView again, we going back to parent fragment (bound to 1st position of BottomNavigationView). But from this point, if I click the button and open the `fragment`, it is always blank.

Here is how my fragment management looks like:

```
fun navigateTo(
            context: Context,
            fragment: BaseFragment,
            navigatable: Navigatable,
            addToBackStack: Boolean
    ) {
        val activity = ContextUtil.getActivityFromContext(context)
        val tag = fragment.javaClass.toString()
        val fragmentManager = (activity as BaseActivity).supportFragmentManager
        val transaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
        if (fragmentManager.findFragmentByTag(fragment.javaClass.toString()) == null) {
            transaction.add(R.id.container, fragment, tag).hide(fragment)
        }
        val activeFragment = findVisibleFragment(context)
        transaction
                .apply {
                    if (activeFragment != null) {
                        hide(activeFragment)
                    }
                }
                .show(fragment)
                .apply {
                    if (addToBackStack) {
                        this.addToBackStack(tag)
                    }
                }
                .commit()
        navigatable.afterScreenTransition(fragment).invoke()
    }
```

I did an experiment and found that `onAttach()` gets called in my `pager fragment`, but all the views are null, `onCreateView()` not called.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after further experimenting, I did `supportFragmentManager.popBackStack()` before opening the 1st fragment. Now opening the child fragment is not blank.